# avoid duplicating a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

i am populating a listview using this snippet code ,but need to check if the value to be taken from the textviw is already there in the listview, does anybody know a good practice for this issue ?

```
 tv.setText(count+" | "+"id: "+uid+"  Sak: "+Sak+"  atqa: "+atqa );
    count++;
    int k=sp.getCount();
    String a1[]=new String[k+1];
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
        a1[i]=sp.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    a1[k]=tv.getText().toString();
    ArrayAdapter<String> ats=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,a1);



    sp.setAdapter(ats);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use AdapterView#getItemAtPosition(int) to get data associated with a row item, as ArrayAdapter itself lets you #getItem(int) and #getCount().

So to get the full array backing the listview. Do:

```
String newItem = "Item to insert";
for(int i=0; i<adapter.getCount(); i++){
   String foo = (Object) adapter.getItem(i);
   if (foo.equals(newItem)){
    return; // do not add
   }
}
adapter.add(newItem); // add it
```

Comment: didn't worked for me because i forgot to mention i'm working inside a newintent handler, so everytime a nfc tag captured got its id added in the array, so here the final working code for me

Answer (score 0):

```
    int k=sp.getCount();
    String a1[]=new String[k+1];

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            a1[i] = sp.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Log.e("test", "test" + a1[i].toString());
            Log.e("test", "orig" + " | " + "id: " + uid + "  Sak: " + Sak + "  atqa: " + atqa);

            String foo = (" | " + "id: " + uid + "  Sak: " + Sak + "  atqa: " + atqa);
            if (foo.equals(a1[i].toString())) {
                Log.e("eqal", "equal");
                return;


            }
        }

    a1[k]=tv.getText().toString();
    ArrayAdapter<String> ats=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,a1);
    Log.e("test","test"+ats.getItem(k));


    sp.setAdapter(ats);
```